# xpath() returns emty list[]

Tags: python, xml, xpath

xpath returns empty list for the following queries.
Need to fetch UrlOne1, UrlOne2, DataOne1, DataOne, DataOne2

```
<table>
<thead></thead>
<tbody class="dataContainer">
    <tr class="tableLight"> 
        <td><a href="UrlOne1" class="ClassOne1">DataOne1</a></td>
        <td> <a href="UrlOne2"><span class="badge"></span> <span class="long">DataOne</span> <span class="short">DataOne</span> </a> </td>
        <td class="hide-s"><span class="ClassOneCN"></span> <span class="ClassOne2">DataOne2</span></td></tr>
    <tr class="tableLight">
    <tr class="tableLight">
    <tr class="tableLight">
```

returns null [] for the following

```
response.xpath('//*[@class="dataContainer"]/a/@href') 
response.xpath('//*[@class="tableLight"]')
response.xpath('//*[local-name() = "tr" and class="tableLight"]')
```

but the code below works fine with answer : ['>]

```
response.xpath('//*[@class="dataContainer"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

For the **first** xpath `//*[@class="dataContainer"]/a/@href`

`//` is the descendant-or-self axis whereas `/` is a direct child of the current node. In this case `a` isn't a direct child so you need to use `//` :

```
//*[@class="dataContainer"]//a/@href
```

The **second** path `//*[@class="tableLight"]` should work, but if you know it's an `tr` tag use it :

```
//tr[@class="tableLight"]
```

And for the **third** xpath `//*[local-name() = "tr" and class="tableLight"]` `class` is an attribute so you need to use `@class` (but I would suggest using the xpath above instead) :

```
//*[local-name() = "tr" and @class="tableLight"]
```

As for your what you need (`UrlOne1, UrlOne2, DataOne1, DataOne, DataOne2`), you could get the `a` elements like so `response.xpath('//tr[@class="tableLight"]//a')` and then retrieve the `href` attribute or text for each `a` element.
Or directly get the `href` attributes and text :

```
//tr[@class="tableLight"]//a/@href
//tr[@class="tableLight"]//a//text()
```